# On windows, how can I list files along with their created, modified and accessed dates?

Tags: windows

The 'dir' command has a /T switch which selects whether to display the creation, access or modification time.  However, it doesn't seem to be able to list files along with all three dates for each file -- how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in MS-DOS. You can only use one time field (C or A or W) for T at a time.

Comment: They’re not asking about DOS, they only added that tag erroneously instead of the `command-prompt` tag (which is redundant anyway since they already used the `dir` tag). Besides, the title clearly says *on windows*.

Answer (score 2):

if you can use Powershell, `ls | fl` (`powershell ls^|fl from cmd`) will show those (among others). You can include only props you need:
`ls | fl -prop name, creationTime,lastAccessTime,LastWriteTime`.
Use `ls | get-member` to see available properties

Comment: `get-childitem d:\temp -rec | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} |
>> select-object FullName, LastWriteTime, creationTime, lastAccessTime,  Length | export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -path file.csv`  will do same recursively

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do that with the Windows command-prompt itself; it only supports a single timestamp column, but you could try third-party alternatives like [4DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4DOS) or [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) (formerly known as Console 2). In fact, open-source ones like Console are best because you can [request the feature](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=43764&atid=437335) (technically Console doesn’t replace the command-interpreter itself, but I’m sure they can extend some commands like this).